# What does this error mean while running the ksvm of kernlab package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, do.call, kernlab

I am calling the ksvm method of the kernlab package in R using the following syntax

```
svmFit = ksvm(x=solTrainXtrans, y=solTrainYSVM, kernel="stringdot", kpar="automatic", C=1, epsilon=0.1)
```

The x parameter is a data.frame with feature values and the y parameter is a list with various values.

I get the following error while run the above line.

```
Error in do.call(kernel, kpar) : second argument must be a list
```

What is it trying to tell me here?

Comment: `kpar="automatic"` is not implemented for this kernel. The parameter expects a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `kpar = list(length = 4, lambda = 0.5)`
Does it help?